# continue playing music when app closes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, backgroundworker, mediaelement

I am developing an app in wp7 and in some part.

I start a mediaelement to play my music file from isolated storage, with available functions(play, pause, next, previous, seek) and all goes perfect!

Now i want to make the app continue playing on user-exit or page-unload or something like that when mediaelement already playing!

Notice in the abobe try the

```
list.playlist: is a list with audiotracks
num_input: is the number of music file in list that will play, (get: from mediaelement)
time_input: is the timespan from mediaelement before stop, (set: backgroundaudioplayer to start)
play: is boolean variable, true if mediaelement plays
Stop(): is function that stops mediaelement from playing
```

Thats i am trying is:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (play == true)
    {
        TimeSpan time_input = med.Position;
        Stop();

        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close();
        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = list.playlist[num_input];
        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Position = time_input;
        if (PlayState.Playing == BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState) {       BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Pause(); }
        else { BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play(); }
        }
}

void Instance_PlayStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState)
    {
        case PlayState.Playing:
            break;

        case PlayState.Paused:
        case PlayState.Stopped:
            break;
     }
}
```

The problem is that when the app page-unload (not on user exit, the first problem)
the backgroundaudioplayer gets the name and the EnabledControls and all staff but it isn't playing even I press the play button(so buttons not working, second problem)!

Also i want to control the list of my app beside that player(previous, next, play, pause) even the app is closed!

All the songs are located in isolated and i have the song-name and file-name in database. The audio track looks like:

```
AudioTrack audiotrack1 = new AudioTrack(new Uri(emp.EmployeeFile + ".mp3", UriKind.Relative), emp.EmployeeName, null, null, null, null, EnabledPlayerControls.All);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing background audio requires more work. See this article for a walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx

Beware the agent lives in another process, I'm not sure whether SqlCe supports concurrent access to the same database from different processes. IMO the best way to communicate with the background agent is the isolated storage file (e.g. the playlist) guarded by the named `System.Threading.Mutex`.

Comment: Get it mind that agent takes the song playlist as variable not from database, like you said! Plan(Database ---> static variable List ---> Agent), i have seen this document but i do not want to control the agent via the app, but the list via agent when app is closed!

Comment: My plan would be Database -> List (in GUI process) -> isolated storage file -> static List (in agent process) -> background audio player. Remember the OS will sometimes terminate your GUI process (e.g. when user press back button enough times, or as the result of tombstoning) while the agent process will live happily, playing your music, and responding to the universal volume control's "next-pause-previous-play" buttons. That's why you need to have your playlist in the background process.

Comment: I see, i also want you to know that i do not get any exception for music file existing or something like this! So how can i set the playlist in agent process?

Comment: When your user press "play" in the GUI process, you save the playlist to the isolated storage, and call `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();`. In your background agent process, when you receive the play command, you load the playlist from the isolated storage, construct AudioTrack obect, and play it. I suggest you to follow the MSDN guide that I've linked to, to get familiar with the whole background audio architecture - it's not that simple, and does require some efforts to implement correctly :-(

Comment: Ok, i made a function that saves the source and title foreach audiotrack from my playlist in txt in isolated. Then i add the agent from the project you linked me in mine(and also the dll in references) and then i made a function that loads the txt in the agent creating the playlist of audiotracks! But it is not playing! I thing is not loading the agent!

Comment: It playssss!!!!!! Thanks Soonts :) i just removed the dll from the project references and add again right(by --> Add reference --> Project tab --> Select, not from a windows directory) i think it built the dll every time before load it!

Comment: Glad I helped. Most likely, re-adding the DLL changed your WMAppManifest.xml file, adding/changing `Deployment/App/Tasks/ExtendedTask` node there.